# Append two multi indexed data frames in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying this simple setup of variables:

```
In [94]: cc
Out[94]: 
                 d0         d1
class sample                    
5     66      0.128320  0.970817
      66      0.160488  0.969077
      77      0.919263  0.008597
6     77      0.811914  0.123960
      88      0.639887  0.262943
      88      0.312303  0.660786

In [101]: bb
Out[101]: 
                     d0         d1
class sample                    
2     22      0.730631  0.656266
      33      0.871292  0.942768
3     44      0.081831  0.714360
      55      0.600095  0.770108

In [102]: aa
Out[102]: 
                     d0         d1
class sample                    
0     00      0.190409  0.789750
      11      0.588001  0.250663
1     22      0.888343  0.428968
      33      0.185525  0.450020
```

I can perform the following command

```
In [103]: aa.append(bb)
Out[103]: 
                     d0         d1
class sample                    
0     00      0.190409  0.789750
      11      0.588001  0.250663
1     22      0.888343  0.428968
      33      0.185525  0.450020
2     22      0.730631  0.656266
      33      0.871292  0.942768
3     44      0.081831  0.714360
      55      0.600095  0.770108
```

Why I cant perform the following command in the same manner?

```
aa.append(cc)
```

[I get the following exception]

```
ValueError: all arrays must be same length
```

### UPDATE:

It works fine if I did not provide column names, but if for example I have 4 columns, with names ['d0','d0','d1','d1'] for 4X4 and 8X4, it does not work anymore

here is the code for reproducing the error

```
import pandas
y1 = [['0','0','1','1'],['00','11','22','33']]
y2 = [['2','2','3','3','4','4'],['44','55','66','77','88','99']]
x1  = np.random.rand(4,4)
x2 = np.random.rand(6,4)
cols = ['d1']*2 + ['d2']*2
names = ['class','idx']
aa = pandas.DataFrame(x1,index=y1,columns = cols)
aa.index.names = names
print aa
bb = pandas.DataFrame(x2,index=y2,columns = cols)
bb.index.names = names
print bb

aa.append(bb)
```

What should I do to get this running?

Thanks

Comment: which data type are you using? Series, DataFrame, Panel, ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
concatenated = pd.concat([bb, cc])

concatenated

                      0         1
class  sample                    
2      22      0.730631  0.656266
       33      0.871282  0.942768
3      44      0.081831  0.714360
       55      0.600095  0.770108
5      66      0.128320  0.970817
       66      0.160488  0.969077
       77      0.919263  0.008597
6      77      0.811914  0.123960
       88      0.639887  0.262943
       88      0.312303  0.660786
```

**Answer To Your Edited Question**

So to answer your edited question, the problem lies with your column names having duplicates.

```
 cols = ['d1']*2 + ['d2']*2  # <-- this creates ['d1', 'd1', 'd2', 'd2']
```

and your dataframes end up having what-is-considered duplicated columns, i.e.

```
In [62]: aa
Out[62]: 
                 d1        d1        d2        d2
class idx                                        
0     00   0.805445  0.442059  0.296162  0.041271
      11   0.384600  0.723297  0.997918  0.006661
1     22   0.685997  0.794470  0.541922  0.326008
      33   0.117422  0.667745  0.662031  0.634429
```

and

```
In [64]: bb
Out[64]: 
                 d1        d1        d2        d2
class idx                                        
2     44   0.465559  0.496039  0.044766  0.649145
      55   0.560626  0.684286  0.929473  0.607542
3     66   0.526605  0.836667  0.608098  0.159471
      77   0.216756  0.749625  0.096782  0.547273
4     88   0.619338  0.032676  0.218736  0.684045
      99   0.987934  0.349520  0.346036  0.926373
```

`pandas.append()` (or `concat()` method) can only append correctly if you have unique column names.

Try this and you will not get any error:-

```
cols2 = ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4']

cc = pandas.DataFrame(x1, index=y1, columns=cols2)
cc.index.names = names

dd = pandas.DataFrame(x2, index=y2, columns=cols2)
cc.index.names = names
```

Now...

```
In [70]: cc.append(dd)
Out[70]: 
                 d1        d2        d3        d4
class idx                                        
0     00   0.805445  0.442059  0.296162  0.041271
      11   0.384600  0.723297  0.997918  0.006661
1     22   0.685997  0.794470  0.541922  0.326008
      33   0.117422  0.667745  0.662031  0.634429
2     44   0.465559  0.496039  0.044766  0.649145
      55   0.560626  0.684286  0.929473  0.607542
3     66   0.526605  0.836667  0.608098  0.159471
      77   0.216756  0.749625  0.096782  0.547273
4     88   0.619338  0.032676  0.218736  0.684045
      99   0.987934  0.349520  0.346036  0.926373
```

Comment: This is my full ipython results - http://dpaste.com/hold/826110/ 
Tell me what is different when you do exactly this in your ipython shell.

Comment: You are right, I forget to mention that I provided the names of the columns as specified on the updated version of the question.

Comment: I actually need the same name for multiple columns. I think in that case I have also to do multi-indexing on column level. Thanks.